# bash on windows 10 error installing shodan

Tags: bash, windows-10, shodan

I have setup bash on windows 10.
Now I am trying to install shodan.
When I run pip install shodan I get error at the end as

```
copying and adjusting bin/shodan -> build/scripts-2.7

changing mode of build/scripts-2.7/shodan from 666 to 777

running install_lib

creating /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/shodan

error: could not create '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/shodan': Permission denied

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip_build_subodh/shodan/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-RXaSEq-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_subodh/shodan
Storing debug log for failure in /home/subodh/.pip/pip.log
subodh@ILPT224:~$
```

Comment: The user you are using to install it doesn't have permission to create that directory. Either use a user that does or change the owner/permissions of the parent directory.

Comment: I tried doing sudo su root user and then pip install shodan but same error. Also when you setup bash on windows by default there is only one user which is root user create. I am using the same user. I am new bee to linux can you please help with the exact commands to resolve this.